# ThreadPoolExecutor, Futures: correlating requests and responses

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, future, threadpoolexecutor

I'm trying to use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) along with [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) (results) and [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) (task to be executed), but I can't figure out a simple way of correlating input (Callable) with the corresponding result (Future), it seems the only sensible way would be to create a wrapper ([example](https://sycure.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/example-using-java-future-and-countdownlatch/)) that contains all items, but this might be too much overhead for such a simple task.

Am I wrong? Any suggested alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better approach would be to use the `invokeAll()` method instead of `submit()`. You need to provide a collection of `Callable`s to it and it will return a collection of `Futures` in the same sequential order as your tasks. Moreover, `invokeAll()` lets you define a timeout, so you don't need latches. It will be something like that:

```
List<Callable> jobs = new ArrayList<>(requests.size());
for (String request : requests) {
    jobs.add(new MyCallable(request));
}
List<Future<ProcessedResponse>> futures = executor.invokeAll(jobs, timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
Iterator<String> it = requests.iterator();
for (Future<ProcessedResponse> future: futures) {
    String request = it.next();  // This request corresponds to this future
    if (future.isDone()) {
        results.add(new Result(request, future.get()));
    } else {
        future.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds great, but my only worry would be about the collections' orders, do I need a specific Collection class or any would do? Where is the "preserve order" speficiation stated?

Comment: All `List`s preserve the elements order. So, you need to pass a list to the executor and it will return you a list of futures. Here's the documentation on the `invokeAll()` method, have a look at the "Returns" section: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-

Comment: just a small typo: the local loop variable should be in singular not plural, i.e. "future", as "futures" is already the whole list. oops: also it reads "fugure.get()", instead of "future.get()"